# Blackberry-10 Cascades

Tags: simulator, blackberry-10

Am new to Blackberry-10 development,i am running an sample BB-10 application while running on blackBerry 10 Dev Alpha Simulator am getting error

[image: the Error is]

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem.!!
Thanks

Comment: Make sure, you. Already create cnnection profile to the simulator

Comment: Double check that you have put simulator into development mode. That setting could be found under Settings > Security and Privacy > Development Mode (set the Use Development Mode option to On)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the VM ware and connect to the simulator with the IP address again

Answer (score 1):

Syncing and starting problems can occur with the simulator, or the Dev Alpha, when the application is running but not under the control of the IDE when you try to start the application again under the IDE control. Usually exiting the application on the simulator or Dev Alpha will solve the problem, but remember to respect the back-off-retry time requirements.

Other issues that cause these problems may be solved by rebooting the simulator OS and/or deleting the application from the simulator.